# Adding an existing folder to SVN outside of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have created a repository online and I want to add an existing folder to it and make it version controlled. I am using TortoiseSVN.

When using Visual Studio I can just click *"Add to Subversion"* and it automatically adds the versioning to my project. When I click into the physical folder everything has icons next to it implying it's now versioned. I can then just commit it all either in or out of visual studio.

My problem is, I now have a folder that isn't part of a Visual Studio project that I want versioned. But I can't work out how to do it. If I click import I can import all the files but it doesn't add the versioning to the folder. I can then export it else where, but still I don't have the versioning.

What do I have to do to make my existing folder versioned without Visual Studio doing it?

Comment: BTW how exactly do you add a solution in VS?

Comment: Right click and click "Add To Subversion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just worked out how to do this, so am answering my own question in case someone else is trying to do this:

1. Create the repository on the server,
2. `svn import` everything into it,
3. `svn checkout` what you just imported over the top of your existing folder.

*Everything now will have ticks by it ready to commit!*

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) manual. At least they'll help you to understand the concept behind Subversion and version-control in general.

When you `svn import` some folder to Subversion you can later get the working copy of this folder by doing a `svn checkout` operation in TortoiseSVN or a command-line client.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever tool you are using in Visual Studio is using a subversion client under the hood - you can normally invoke this tool directly from the command line if wanted.

If you are not comfortable with that, you can download and install the free [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) tool that integrates with the windows shell. Once installed, you can right click on the files/folders to add them to your repository outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have to TortoiseSVN tool.. and sorry but I've just worked out how to do it! Will post below!